# Fastest way to assign item from a list to another item in a list

Tags: c#, performance, linq, list

I've two class which is product and order, please look at the class attribute blow

```
public class Product()
{ 
  public int ProductId { get;set; }
  public string ProductName { get;set; }
  public List<Order> OrderList { get;set; }
}

public class Order()
{
  public int OrderId { get;set; }
  public int ProductId { get;set; }
  public string OrderNumber { get;set; }
  public string OrderDescription { get;set; }
}
```

and i have a separate call to get the data from each of the class

```
var productList = ProductService.GetAllProductList();
var orderList = OrderService.GetAllOrderList();
```

What i'm trying to achieve here is that i want to assign order list object to product, i can achieve this by doing like below

```
  foreach(var product in productList)
  {
     var selectedOrderList = orderList.Where(x => x.ProductId = product.ProductId).ToList();
     product.OrderList = selectedOrderList;
  }
```

Imaging if my product and order has large amount of data, it could caused some performance issue.

It's because we are doing unnecessary lookup in orderList as some of the order data is already assigned.

Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: It really depends on what `productList` and `orderList` actually are - from what you've posted they could be anything, eg IQueryables off to a database etc.  Have you _actually got_ a performance problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Are you using entity framework

Comment: im not using entity framework, the service i've used in above is calling from database and it return List<Product> and List<Order>

Comment: You could implement both ways and use a StopWatch to test which one is faster ;)

Comment: To minimize the number of lookups in the list you could use a dictionary which maps product ids to a list oder orders. That way you only need to traverse the orderlist once to create the dictionary. But that does not mean it will be faster overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's because we are doing unnecessary lookup in orderList

I would not call it *unnecessary*, but for sure it is *inefficient* due to linear time complexity of the LINQ to Objects `Where` method, leading to O(N * M) complexity of the processing algorithm.

So you need a fast alternative, and the easiest standard (and quite efficient hash based implementation) is to build and use `Order`s [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx) by `ProductId` using [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which will trim the time complexity to O(N + M):

```
var ordersByProductId = orderList.ToLookup(order => order.ProductId);
foreach (var product in productList)
     product.OrderList = ordersByProductId[product.ProductId].ToList();
```

Comment: This is really good i.e idea of lookup.Thanks for teaching us to do things in a better way.This will really help me at so many places where i have committed this kind of mistakes like OP :)

Comment: It's really useful, tested and the performance is obviously improved. Thanks

Comment: Won't an Inner join work better than Look Up, which needs first creation of look up data structure

Comment: @MrinalKamboj It's basically the same - `GroupJoin` [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1bdae7e7505451ef), note the first line. I would use join if the query is projecting the result, for update I think using explicit lookup is cleaner and less error prone - with LINQ query one can easily forget to execute it by enumerating it :)

Comment: Thanks Ivan for explaining the details

Answer (score 0):

If you are already returning a list of all orders from the service in orderList... then doing a linq WHERE from a list in memory shouldn't have any performance issues.

Or you change the service to populate product.OrderList before returning it.

Comment: Where clause will have a deferred execution WhereListIterator, which would need to be again converted back to List or relevant data structure, therefore memory conversion shall be the very last operation

Comment: But the .ToList will make sure it's not deferred, right?

Comment: Where clause is post ToList, followed by another ToList as I understand Product and Order List are already allocated in the memory, that's double whammy